# Do I need to separate my main and gas grounding conductors?

Tags: nec, grounding-and-bonding

I have a garage with the electrical meter and gas meter on one side, and the water and grounding rods on the other side.

I understand that the meter needs to be bonded to the water pipe and grounding rods within 5 ft of the water pipe entry. And the gas line also needs to be bonded at the water pipe entry too. As far as I can tell, I am *not* allowed to bond the meter and gas line, then have a single ground to the water line.

What I am confused on is that since the conductors will be following a parallel path, do I need to keep the copper physically separated or insulated from each other until they meet at the water line? They will be in flexible conduit -- does the conduit need to be physically kept separate?

[image: my garage]

Edit:

Here is an image I found on Google. It shows the "Main protective bonding conductors" from various parts of the house all converging at the "Main earthing terminal". They are **not** allowed to be bonded together until they reach that main earthing terminal. **Are they required to be insulated from eachother until that point?**

[image: image from Google]

Comment: The second of your pictures shows the standard in the UK.  Here we normally use insulated wire (with a green and yellow stripey sheath) for bonding.  So they are naturally insulated from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if the wires contact each other.  What matters is they are not cut and spliced anywhere they're not allowed to be, e.g. anywhere along the Grounding Electrode Conductor.

The ground rods provide your system Grounding Electrode, or reference to actual earth. They establish your house grounding.  They keep your electrical system near the voltage of actual earth, and are frequently featured in wiring problems such as Lost Neutral from the utility.

The water or gas pipe *bonding* is to keep those pipes near system ground voltage, so a pipe isn't floated up to wild voltages due to equipment malfunction or what have you.

I realize these functions seem to overlap *a lot* but you have to assume your utility replaced their lines with plastic.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question. OK - I have the main bonded with the ground rods, the system grounding electrode. Now, when I bond my gas line, does the gas line's grounding conductor need to be physically kept separate from my meter's grounding conductor?

Comment: @000 edited to answer more directly.  I think you saw.